# How would i make it so that when i copy and paste the command button it will make the code apply to the newly pasted section instead of the older one?

Tags: excel, vba

In excel
For exampple: the code i have currently is as you see below.

I want to be able to copy and paste this form:

[image]

into the next rows and have the code apply in those new rows as well (when i click the macro button). Currently if i paste the form to a new row and use the buttons, it will only apply to the first form that i made these buttons on.

```
Sub APPROVED5K()
' APPROVED5K Macro

    Range("O5:Q7").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "APPROVED"
    Range("O9:Q9").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "5000"
    Range("O5:Q7").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Kind of difficult to know what's going on without the column/row headers...

Comment: If you want the code to be outputting values to a specific area, you need to change those range addresses to the new area. like `Range("O5:Q7")` needs to be rewritten for every button to point at new addresses. You might be able to use a property of the button to calculate the new address based on the new location of the button, like `Range("O" & Me.TopLeftCell.Row).Resize(2,2)`. But I don't know enough about your sheet to give specific advice.

Comment: How did you create the original button?

Comment: I used insert shape to make the button, then made the macro using record. I was hoping i could have the button calculate new address like toddleson mentioned. So lets say i have the initial buttons doing its recorded steps on O6 I would like when i copy and paste the next set of buttons to change so now its doing the recorded address on O10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's sometimes easier to use hyperlinks instead of buttons if you want to be able to have multiple copies and easily be able to copy/paste existing ranges with buttons (ie. without the buttons drifting off their locations, or if you want to be able to handle sorting of the data for example).

Eg: insert this function in a regular module

```
Function LinkMe()
    Set LinkMe = Application.ThisCell
End Function
```

All this does is serve as a Target for the hyperlink, so the selection doesn't jump around when the user clicks on a link. Hyperlinks need to link *to* something, so this just returns the range for the clicked-on link.

Create your "action" links in place of buttons, using `Insert > Link` with appropriate *Text to display* values ("Approve", 'Deny" etc) and use `#LinkMe` for the *Address*.  Note you can't use the `HYPERLINK()` formula to create links if you want to use them this way.

Now you can set up the code to respond to click on the links. Right-click the tab for the sheet where your links will be, and select "View Code". Paste the Sub below into that code module:

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)
    HandleLink Target 'call the handler in a regular module
End Sub
```

Note *as an alternative to the above*, there's also a Workbook-level event handler if you want to handle link clicks regardless of the worksheet, so in the `ThisWorkbook` code module you could put this:

```vb
Private Sub Workbook_SheetFollowHyperlink(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Hyperlink)
    HandleLink Target 'call the handler
End Sub
```

Then in a regular module you create the `HandleLink` method called by the event handler above. This method get the clicked link and decides what action should be taken, using the link's `TextToDisplay` (eg. "Approve" etc) and `Range` properties.

```vb
'Called from `Worksheet_FollowHyperlink`
Sub HandleLink(lnk As Hyperlink)
    Dim txt As String, c As Range, rng As Range
    
    txt = lnk.TextToDisplay    'what's the link disply text
    Set c = lnk.Range.Cells(1) 'and where is it located
    
    Debug.Print "Clicked link '" & txt & "' in " & c.Address & _
                " on " & c.Parent.Name
    
    If txt = "Approve" Then
        'locate a range *relative to the link cell* and do something
        '  eg: two columns to the right and 2 rows x 5 columns
        Set rng = c.Offset(0, 2).Resize(2, 5)
        rng.Value = "OK" 'populate that range
    End If
    
    If txt = "Deny" Then
        'take some other action here...
    End If
    
    'etc etc for other link texts
    
End Sub
```

Comment: This seems like the an amazing way to do what im trying to do but i am still a novice with vba. What do you mean by insert this function in a regular module? is a regular module not a shape?

Edit: I figured out how to enter a module on vba so ill keep going through your instructions until i am stuck

Comment: A "regular" code module is a code module which does not belong to a worksheet or ThisWorkbook, and is not a Class module.

Comment: okay so i got to the part of the creating the action link, i am lost at this point. Could you use example cells in your instructions or am i just putting exactly what you have here?

Comment: to be more precise, I have the module, and the hyper link address set to #linkme. Not sure where to now when it comes to the action part

Comment: I can’t post now but will get back to you later

Comment: No worries! thank you for your time. I await your return

Comment: I've updated my answer to re-arrange the code, and added some more detail. Let me know if you're still having problems.